# Piano song played with three hands, heard in romantic films

Tags: identify-this-song, piano

I'm currently looking for a piano song which is heard in multiple films. I can't remember the name of those films although. The piano song is played with three hands.

The song is often played in a romantic scene where the man play the piano with two hands and a girl will just play some notes with the right hand (one finger should be enough though). I can't exactly remember the tones but for the girl the three first notes are the same.

So I'm looking for the name of this song and the name of some movies where the song is played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty confident you're looking for [Heart And Soul](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijt5yjlbvVAhVGJMAKHadsD0kQyCkIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DibfJsyx6N_U&usg=AFQjCNECjNYx-D5peFTk1fWDOdAqRbaR5g).

I remember they played it on an episode of Lost, and at least on Stuart Little.